# Python: Check whether my string contains non ascii chars

Tags: python, eclipse, string, encoding, character-encoding

I work with dictionary and I want to detect keys which contains non-english characters like 'č' for example.

This is my code:

```
for i in dictionaryMemory.keys():
            czechChars=['á','é','í','ó','ů','ě','ř','ť','č','š','ž']
            if any(s in i for s in czechChars):
                dictionaryMemory.pop(i)
                print(i)
```

But when I try to run this code, eclipse prints that `SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xc3' in file...`

Ok, so I try to put `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-`¨. It seems to work, but it can't find any of these characters. What to do?

EDIT: In the project properties I found this: `Text file encoding: inherited from container(Cp1250)`

I have a problems with encoding very usually but can't still figure out how to do it in a proper way...

Comment: Note that after adding `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` eclipse has a tendency to convert all non-ascii characters already in the file to ?. So make sure that after you add that, and save - they're not all deleted.

Comment: Change the coding comment from `utf-8` to `cp1250`.

Comment: Thank you guys, both answers helped me!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Tal Kremerman and Mark Ransom said, I tried to change the coding comment from `utf-8` to `cp1250` and then I checked, whether the chars in my code were in proper format, they did not so I changed them to `č,š,ř...` and finally it works!